# Extracting probabilities from a softmax layer in [tensorflow 1.00]

Tags: python, tensorflow, neural-network

Using tensorflow, I have an LSTM classification model with a softmax as the final node.
This is my softmax layer:

```
with tf.name_scope("Softmax") as scope:
            with tf.variable_scope("Softmax_params"):
                softmax_w = tf.get_variable("softmax_w", [hidden_size, num_classes])
                softmax_b = tf.get_variable("softmax_b", [num_classes])
            logits = tf.nn.xw_plus_b(output, softmax_w, softmax_b) # Predicted label, eg y = tf.matmul(X, W) + b)

            loss = tf.nn.sparse_softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(labels=self.labels,
                                                                  logits=logits,
                                                                  name='softmax')
```

My question is when evaluating this model with novel data, how can I extract the probabilities for each class?

```
num_class = 129

for i in range(runs):
    X_batch, y_batch = sample_batch(X_test[:200], y_test[:200], batch_size)
    predictions = sess.run([model.logits], feed_dict = {model.input: X_batch, model.keep_prob: 1.0})
```

Comment: what is wrong with the predictions variable?

Comment: Nothing is wrong, I just wanted to know if there is a most ideal way of getting the probabilities for each class.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just add the line

```
probs = tf.nn.softmax(logits)
```

Then do

```
predictions = sess.run(model.probs, feed_dict=feed_dict)
```